# Using Ruby AWS SDK to create a Route53 alias to a Cloudfront distribution

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to automate creating an S3 backed CloudFront cached website served on a Route53 managed DNS.

I can create the S3 bucket with static website hosting and I know how to create a CloudFront distribution and a Route53 record, but when creating a Route53 record that is an alias to a CloudFront distribution one needs to provide a "hosted zone id" - which the Route53 interface has no problems finding, but I can't figure out how to use the AWS SDK to get that information.

Here's what I have:

```
def create_cf(domain)
  AWS::CloudFront.new.client.create_distribution distribution_config: createOptions(domain)
end

def create_r53(cfdistro, domain)
  target = {
    hosted_zone_id: cfdistro.id,
    dns_name: cfdistro.domain_name,
    evaluate_target_health: false
  }
  AWS::Route53.new.hosted_zones[myzone].rrsets.create "#{domain}.", 'A',
    alias_target: target
end
```

Unfortunately, the field `id` returned from `create_distribution` (or `get_distribution`) is what the CloudFront console shows as the ID of the distributions, but is not what Route53's console shows when I select the CloudFront distribution as an alias target. I actually couldn't figure out where to find the hosted zone ID in the CloudFront console!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was silly - as documented in [AWS Route53 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/CreateAliasRRSAPI.html), all CloudFront distributions are hosted in the zone whose ID is `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`.

The "hosted zone ID" (I discovered after further reading) is the cryptographic identifier of a Route53 zone. The Route53 zone ids for public AWS domains (such as cloudfront.net) are published by Amazon in their documentation, exactly for this purpose.

Do my code above should be:

```
def create_r53(cfdistro, domain)
  target = {
    hosted_zone_id: 'Z2FDTNDATAQYW2',
    dns_name: cfdistro.domain_name,
    evaluate_target_health: false
  }
  AWS::Route53.new.hosted_zones[myzone].rrsets.create "#{domain}.", 'A',
    alias_target: target
end
```